# Why does ssh X forwarding timeout after a while?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

So I have a mac at work which I like to ssh into my linux box with something like this:

```
$ ssh -Xt user@mylinux
```

I can login and start any X11 apps on my linux box no problem.  But after 15 minutes or so, I come back to a session (ssh is still running and connected) and I get:

```
$ xterm 
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0
```

I've tried using `-o "TCPKeepAlive yes"` or `-o "ServerAliveInterval 30"`, but still get the same behavior.

Is there something in ssh or on the Mac or my linux sshd conf that kills X-forwarding after a period of inactivity?

Comment: Is the X server still running? Do existing X apps get killed?

Comment: (would comment on Bob's 2012-11-18 answer, but it won't let me yet) See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107547/disable-forwardx11timeout-without-forwardx11trusted-in-openssh-client in which we find that you cannot (in 2019) disable this timeout, but you can extend it. The maximum timeout is uint_max of milliseconds minus some slack, just over 24 days. OpenSSH_7.4p1 will accept `ssh -o ForwardX11Timeout=2147423s -X ...` which is the best answer I can make now. ForwardX11Timeout above this may crash the XServer in some version combinations. On MacOS with XQuartz, I have seen `Warni

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default `ForwardX11Timeout` is 20 minutes for `ssh -X`, but you can set it to something large (e.g. `7d` for 7 days) in `.ssh/config`

"Trusted" X11 forwarding via `ssh -Y` actually enables potentially nasty things like keystroke monitoring and screen grabs.

Comment: `man ssh_config` for this option documentation :)

Answer (score 20):

Using `-X`, X11 forwarding is enabled in "Untrusted" mode, making use of various X11 security extensions, including a time-limited Xauth cookie.

Use `-Y` to enable "Trusted" mode for X11, which will enable complete access to your X11 server.